# How do I customize the Spring Boot AccessTokenProvider?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, spring-boot, azure-active-directory

I want to enhance the token request for my OAuth2 provider.  I need to add an additional parameter to the POST request.  I don't understand where to hook into the Spring Boot framework to accomplish this.

The Spring Boot framework provides a hook for customizing the OAuth2RestTemplate as described in "[Customizing the User Info RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html#boot-features-security-custom-user-info)".  I have implemented the following customizer, which gets instantiated and called as expected.  Unfortunately, my provider does not seem to get called when the token request is made.

```
public class AadUserInfoRestTemplateCustomizer implements UserInfoRestTemplateCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate) {

        oAuth2RestTemplate.setAuthenticator(new AadOauth2RequestAuthenticator());

        // Attempt 1: Use my own token provider, but it never gets called...
        oAuth2RestTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(new AadAccessTokenProvider());

        // Even better, if only OAuth2RestTemplate provided a getter for AccessTokenProvider, I could add interceptors and or enhancers
        // Can't do this :( AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider provider = oAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessTokenProvider();
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:**

How does set a custom AccessTokeProvder, or even better, get a reference to the default one and hook into the request with an interceptor or enhancer?

**CODE SAMPLE**

In the fork below, please see the /simple module.  Add your AAD tenant info into the /simple/src/main/resources/application.yml file:

https://github.com/bmillerbma/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/aad

**NOTES:**

- [This commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/commit/df0d04dc4617cc7961b260b21626b2c5f6b20056) to the framework seems to make this possible, but how does one leverage this functionality?
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424715/requestenhancer-not-used-for-authorizationcodeaccesstokenprovider-during-getredi) seems to be related.  Somehow the fella added a custom provider.  But where?

Comment: Do you have a minimal sample project? It's hard to see why the `AadAccessTokenProvider` in the code snippet above would not be used.

Comment: Please see "code sample" section.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I added the resource to my config file and added the following two classes to capture the OAuth2RestTemplate and add request enhancers.

application.yaml:

```
aad:
  resource: https://graph.windows.net

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: [clientid]
etc.
```

---

```
@Component
public class AzureRequestEnhancerCustomizer {
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2RestTemplate userInfoRestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private AzureRequestEnhancer azureRequestEnhancer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void testWiring() {
        AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider authorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider = new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider();
        authorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.setTokenRequestEnhancer(azureRequestEnhancer);
        userInfoRestTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(authorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class AzureRequestEnhancer implements RequestEnhancer {
    @Value("${aad.resource:null}")
    private String aadResource;

    @Override
    public void enhance(AccessTokenRequest request, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, MultiValueMap<String, String> form, HttpHeaders headers) {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(resource)) {
            form.set("resource", aadResource);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across with the same issue and used this workaround but because of this I stuck with spring boot 1.3.8

So I started to dig deeper and then I finally found an easier method. Just add a resource parameter after the `userAuthorizationUri`.

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      ...
      userAuthorizationUri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<tenantId>>/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.windows.net
      ...
```