# Azure AD and Spring Security with Oauth 2

Tags: java, security, spring-mvc, oauth, azure-active-directory

We are trying to implement a SSO scheme using Azure AD and Spring security.
We found a few leads:

https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2

https://github.com/Pytry/azure-b2c-oauth2

But none of these tell the full story.
In fact we can't get passed the access token parsing, Spring has a different idea of what the JWT token should be.

Ideally we wouldn't want to write an SSO filter from scratch but override the Token Services to implement custom filtering for starters.

Has anyone successfully implemented this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any update on this.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** I found an easier method. Just add a resource parameter after the `userAuthorizationUri`.

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      ...
      userAuthorizationUri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<tenantId>>/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.windows.net
      ...
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45828135/2231168

---

**Original answer**

At my office we found a foreign blog post which lead us to the final implementation http://statemachine.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/04/19/155920

As a workaround, you had to add two classes to capture OAuth2RestTemplate and request enhancers. It works with spring boot 1.3.8 which contains spring 4.2.8, we couldn't make it work with higher version.

application.yml:

```
azure:
  resource: https://graph.windows.net
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: <<your client id>>
      clientSecret: <<your client secret>>
      accessTokenUri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<tenantId>>/oauth2/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<tenantId>>/oauth2/authorize
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
      scope: openid
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6
```

AzureRequestEnhancer:

```
@Component
public class AzureRequestEnhancer implements RequestEnhancer {
    @Value("${azure.resource:null}")
    private String aadResource;

    @Override
    public void enhance(AccessTokenRequest request, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, MultiValueMap<String, String> form, HttpHeaders headers) {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(resource)) {
            form.set("resource", aadResource);
        }
    }
}
```

AzureRequestEnhancerCustomizer:

```
@Component
public class AzureRequestEnhancerCustomizer {
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2RestTemplate userInfoRestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private AzureRequestEnhancer azureRequestEnhancer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void testWiring() {
        AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider authorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider = new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider();
        authorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.setTokenRequestEnhancer(azureRequestEnhancer);
        userInfoRestTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(authorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider);
    }
}
```

The `PostConstruct` annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization.

I hope this helps you with the implementation.